# Question view count error in profile page

Tags: bug

One of my question in SO [Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging) has only **1532** view counts, But when i look into my profile where all my questions are listed it is shown as **2k Views**, even when i hover on this **2k** the tooltip shows **1532** views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question view count in that view is rounded to the nearest thousand if the count is over one thousand.

For example:

```
This number | would map to this version
-----------------------------------------------
     13     |              13
    356     |             356
    996     |             996
   1117     |              1k
   1576     |              2k
   2449     |              2k
   2515     |              3k
```

Virtually all rounded things (timestamps, views, etc.) can be disambiguated by hovering.